# 'out' parameter versus generic/template argument: best practice

Tags: c#, generics, out

I'm doing some data parsing and came across this issue. Say we want to parse some `byte[]` to a structure. I want to wrap the C# code that does that into a static method.

The original code (I am reworking a piece) read:

```
public class DiagnosticUndefined : BaseDiagnostic
{
    StructDiagnosticUndefined bufferAllocation;

    public DiagnosticUndefined(byte[] buff)
    {
        bufferAllocation = (StructDiagnosticUndefined)DiagnosticUtil.parseStruct(buff, typeof(StructDiagnosticUndefined));
    }
}
```

I'd like to use a generic function for that, but how to proceed? Consider:

```
public static class Util {
    public static T Convert<T>(byte[] data) {...}
    public static void Convert<T>(byte[] data, out T structure) {...}
}
```

The first is more inline with normal procedure but is has the downside that the compiler cannot infer the datatype so my call will look like this:

```
SomeStruct s;
s = Util.Convert<SomeStruct>(data);
```

The other approach is this:

```
SomeStruct s;
Util.Convert(data, out s);
```

I like the second approach as it delegates the type inference to the compiler i.e. less runtime errors. On the other hand I tend to avoid use of the out parameter as supported by MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx. I'm all for the "don't solve simple problems in a complex way" paradigm but I can't differentiate this time...

Any hints, opinions?

**Update**

The code examples are simplified, the variable is actually a member so I can't go 'one-line'. Also I am using Marshalling to convert the data into a structure:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
T output = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
handle.Free();
```

Comment: The first should look no more complicated than `var s = Util.Convert<SomeStruct>(data);`

Comment: You say "I like the second approach as it delegates the type inference to the compiler i.e. less runtime errors". This sentence is strange in this context, because in both approaches a runtime error because of the type is impossible. In both cases the compiler checks that the types match.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The function version allows implicit conversions, such as `decimal d = Util.Convert<int>(data);`.

Comment: @hvd: Alright - but that still doesn't lead to a runtime error.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth `Util.Convert<int>` could throw an exception if `data.Length` does not match the expected length for an `int`, or could return data that is completely different from what `Util.Convert<decimal>` would have returned. Wrong data is also a runtime error, just not a runtime exception.

Comment: Right you are, this doesn't move my type checking to compile time at all. In a way it's just aesthetics, still I'd like to know the best practice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT Suggested by @Nebula**

The first case, seems perfectly valid one:

```
var s = Util.Convert<SomeStruct>(data);
```

Use `out` when you want somethign back from the call, but *not* for declarative purposes.

Comment: I guess, OP wants to use it as in the second example: `var s = Util.Convert(data);` without explicitly coding T

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov: don't see a *reason* of not using generics declaration, pretending type safity and use *out* parameter, honestly.

Comment: @Tigran What Konstantin said. I don't fully understand your comment. Are you pleading for or against explicitly typing he generic?

Comment: @Nebula: indeed. I say, there is no reason to **not** using generics if you want esplicit type declaration for compiler. Use generics, in other words.

Comment: @Tigran Ok then I understood correctly. And this is opposed to using an 'out' parameter correct?

Comment: @Nebula: yes, for esplicitly declaring type your function operates on *out* is not something you need to use, just use *generics*. Use *out* in case when you want somethign back from the call, but not for declarative purposes.

Comment: @Tigran Right, that sounds more like an answer. If I follow up on this statement I'd say that that I am using the generic as a constructor of sorts. In which case I should declare type. Maybe I can conclude that it generally is bad practice to have a generic out argument? And that I should use an alternative to `out T` if there is any? Update your answer if you concur and I can give you credit for your constructive input.

Comment: @Nebula: no, it's not bad to have *out* generic parameter. Sometimes it's something that you need. What I mean, is that *out* or *non out* is not relevant in regard of the question you asking.

Comment: @Tigran Ok, accepted. I'll keep that in the back of my mind. Still, from what I understand it is better to use generics when I can? As opposed to generic out? I'd like to fully understand you answer so I can answer the question for myself (or others) if I run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @Nebula: I mean *out* parameter presence or absence has nothing to do with decision either use generics or not. It's *completely* different subject of discussion. Use generics where appropriate(often if you wish), but keeping an eye on several drawbacks with them, cause the code for every generic is dupplicated for every new type you declare.

Comment: @Tigran Well the IL code is. And only if you use that particular type at runtime. C++ templates are a hell of a lot worse in performance compared to C# generics. Still I feel that I still haven't got an answer to the question. Would you choose a different approach?

Comment: @Nebula: I would choose your first case. Cause it does what you want (considering the question provided).

Comment: @Tigran Ok, thanks. I edited your answer to reflect this discussion. Feel free to refine. I'll accept this as the answer after you accept the changes ;-)

Comment: @Nebula: here is no way I can *accept* or *reject* your comment. So I will put it like my edit, mantioning your post. Thx !

Answer (score 2):

I would modify the first to:

```
SomeStruct s = Util.Convert<SomeStruct>(data);
```

and go with that.

The reason is less code to read at and maintain.

Comment: The variable being a member doesn't prevent you from writing `_s = Util.Convert<SomeStruct>(data);`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No, but that's what it was right? But then the argument of less code goes away because both solutions reads one line. The argument of less maintaining: the generic has a type dependent argument whereas the 'out' param has not. When I change the type of the output I have to change two lines in the generics solution (var type and gen arg type) in the 'out' solution I only have to change the type of the variable and rest follows automatically. But then I'm back to my question; 'out': less type dependent code, generics: considered more 'correct' in most cases. Is this an exception?

Comment: @Nebula, I don't really the fact that C# lets you pass a private class member as an out parameter to en external method.  This effectively gives code outside the class the ability to update internal class data.  If memory serves correctly, C++ did not allow this, which I think is better and more OO.  So, I know C# allows it, but I would still choose the return parameter, as my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches, needless to create `SomeStruct` object:

```
 SomeStruct s = new SomeStruct();
```

Because I believe you create this object inside `Convert` method. For the second approach, the correctness should be:

```
SomeStruct s;
Util.Convert(data, out s);
```

Because `out` arguments need not be initialized. If you just change properties of `s` and don't change the pointer or create object inside `Convert`, `out` will not be needed also:

```
SomeStruct s = new SomeStruct();
Util.Convert(data, s);
```

IMHO, approach 1 should be better and more readable.

Comment: +1: for the idea to have `SomeStruct` constructed somewhere before and remove `out` modifier => then OP has the desired type inferrence and avoids `out`.

Comment: I don't actually create the object beforehand. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thank you for clarifying the other options available though.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I don't desire the type inferrence, I actually wonder if it is good practice to use this. So please, give me you opinion so I can form mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure using generics in this case will not bring you much of an advantage. But if you insist...
What's wrong with

```
var s = Util.Convert<SomeStruct>(d);
```

Also, converting and parsing is not the same thing, don't use that interchangeably.

Comment: Yeah, I know. My production code has a different name, more appropriate to the task. The above code is an example. The advantage the generics bring me is that instead of writing a function that returns `object`, which I have to cast, I can define the type using C# syntax i.e. more readable.

Comment: By the way, care to elaborate on the "I'm pretty sure using generics in this case will not bring you much of an advantage" part? Not really constructive this way. If you have a better approach then I'd gladly hear it. It IS a best practice question after all.

Comment: Well I didn't know you're using Marshal to the "converting". That's quite unorthodox for C# code. So if you insist on using that, then ignore this comment of mine.
Otherwise, a method that reads in binary data and produces an object would most probably be called Deserialize and would be type specific: SomeStruct DeserializeSomeStruct(byte[] input);